# Как передать заголовки из PHP в JS?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post, header

Есть следующая проблема:

Допустим, я отправляю данные формы в PHP через стандартный submit формы, без использования js. На стороне PHP я обрабатываю данные формы и формирую заголовки для формирования Эксель файла, которые вывожу командой echo:

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Rep' . '.csv');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
echo "num;date;phone;fio;status;\n";
/* Здесь формируемы данные по циклу */
exit;
```

Такой вариант работает хорошо, и по итогу отработки скрипта у меня скачивается файл.

Но что делать, если мне нужно отправить запрос не стандартным submit формы из html, а POST-запросом из JS в PHP?

```
    $('#dont_issue').click(function() {
        $.post('/admin/plugins/subscribe/index.php?act=analyticDownload', {'id': id}, function (res) {
        });
    });
```

Таким образом я передаю ID в PHP-скрипт, который получает данные из базы данных и в итоге должен сформировать Эксель файл с соответствующими заголовками.
Т.е. теперь все заголовки и данные формируемые в серверной части теперь должны возвращаться в JS. Как указать JS-скрипту, что он должен запустить скачивание файла так же, как  и в первом случае?

Comment: Вы, кстати, путаете excel-файлы и csv-файлы, это совершенно разные форматы

Comment: Да, вы правы, в данном случае, это csv файл

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: url,
data: params,
success: function(response, status, xhr) {
    // читаем заголовок от PHP и получаем имя файла
    var filename = "";
    var disposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
    if (disposition && disposition.indexOf('attachment') !== -1) {
        var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
        var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
        if (matches != null && matches[1]) filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');
    }

    var type = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');
    var blob = new Blob([response], { type: type });

    if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== 'undefined') {
        //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772331(v=vs.85).aspx
        //Сохраняем на диск
        window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
    } else {
        var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        if (filename) {
            // создадим ссылку с атрибутом HTML5 a[download] для указания имени файла
            var a = document.createElement("a");

            if (typeof a.download === 'undefined') {
                window.location = downloadUrl;
            } else {
                a.href = downloadUrl;
                a.download = filename;
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
            }
        } else {
            window.location = downloadUrl;
        }

        setTimeout(function () { URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl); }, 100); // чистим мусор)
    }
}
});
```

Осторожно используются экспериментальные технологии ;)
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/URL/revokeObjectURL

Answer (score 1):

Можно еще поступить так (правда немного зашкварно)
На серверной части "отрендерить" JavaScript код

Например

```
<?php
    $someHeaderParam = 'XMLHttpRequest';
    $script = <<<EOF
       <script>
           var header = {$someHeaderParam};
       </script>
    <<<EOF;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', '.dont_issue', function (e) {
    // твои инпуты с которых ты собираешь все данные
    var id = $('input[name=id]').val();
    // можно добавлять сколько угодно параметров. В ajax url полетит этот пост 
    // и ты сможешь там поставить вывод print_r($_POST) имена массива будут 
    // заданы в ajax data. В своей ссылке оставь формирования Эксель файла.
    // если ajax не словит ошибку то файлик скачается.
    // результат по нажатию можешь глянуть в брузере f12 network -> preview
    $.ajax({
        url: '/admin/plugins/subscribe/index.php',
        data: 'id=' + id +
              '&act=analyticDownload',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function () {
            $('#result_div').html('Успех!');
        },
    });
});
```